# M2 | How to check extension attribute is working or not?

Tags: magento2.3, customer-attribute, extension-attributes

I created an extension attribute for customer as:

**Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="expiring_balance" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="get_customer_expiring_balance" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomerPlugin" sortOrder="-1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
class CustomerPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Amount\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_creditFactory;

    public function __construct(
     \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Amount\CollectionFactory $creditFactory,
     \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency) {
        $this->_creditFactory = $creditFactory;
    }
   /**
     * Plugin after getById customer that obtains newsletter subscription status for given customer.
     *
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CustomerInterface $customer
     * @return CustomerInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetById(CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject, CustomerInterface $customer)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            /** @var CustomerExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
            $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionFactory->create(CustomerInterface::class);
            $customer->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }
        if ($extensionAttributes->getExpiringBalance() === null) {

           $creditDetails = $this->_creditFactory->create()->setOrder('date_expires', 'asc');
           foreach ($creditDetails as $Card) {

           $renewAmount = $Card->getRedeemAmount() - $Card-
           $extensionAttributes->setExpiringBalance($renewAmount);
        }
        return $customer;
    }
}
```

I want to see if it is working or not, I am getting customer collection but I cannot see extension attribute here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it, code is fine we can see extension attributes using endpoint:

> GET: V1/customers/me